# Starting another Java process from a running Java process shows OS-dependent behavior

Tags: java

I have this code that calls `java -cp somejar.jar com.company.mainClass`. I am calling it using process builder. In windows, it works fine. In linux, I get the error

> Could not find or load main class com.company.mainClass.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add(java);
args.add("-cp");
args.add("../dep/jetty-distribution-8.1.1.v20120215/lib/*;../build/jar/somejar.jar");
//args.add("../build/jar/LRM.jar");
args.add("com.company.mainClass");
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Any one know why I might be getting different behavior in windows versus linux?

Comment: It's never a good idea to depend on relative paths in your code. You should fully qualify those paths and try the test again.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a semicolon as a path separator, while on unix it is a colon.

Use `File.pathSeparatorChar` instead

Comment: +1 for the File.pathSeparator. I used to use System.getProperty("path.separator"), which does the same, but is not as convenient.

Answer (score 2):

The items in a classpath (-cp) under linux have to be seperated by a colon `:` and under windows by a semicolon `;`. And in windows path seperators are backslashes instead of slashes. Build your classpath with `File.separator`, although it should also work with slashes.

Comment: Was just about to write that, but wanted to make sure that this is correct. Thanks for the comment.